# Multiple processes in PHP

Tags: php

I've written a program that uses `fsockopen()` and `fgets()` to read a website's content on the net or downloading a file onto my server from the net.

It uses the `While` command to receive headers. The problem is: when the script is processing `While`, a unique client can not request another page on my website and it will wait until `While()` finishes its processing.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: In what kind of environment are you running this? A multi-threaded web server like Apache should usually take care of this...

Comment: It's already running on Apache 2, But LocalHost... Any difference?

Comment: There probably is. However, your problem is not clear.

You made a script to read data from the web. It seems like you are overloading your server some how IF you are running said script via Apache. Apache handles multiple requests fine. Are you using Windows or some kind of nix?

Comment: Do you use sessions? Is the page that takes so long requested by that unique client?

Comment: yup, it uses sessions. and yes. ...

Comment: i found the problem!....when i don't use session_start(), everything works fine!! :D .... now, can someone plz explain the complication!!? 8-}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a multiple session_start() call problem!!
i used session_write_close() at the end of my files which started with session_start(), and now everything works fine.
Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

We were using the [Process Forking](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/php/process-forking/) in our projects. As I know it works on *nix systems only. Also it can be run without web server.

Answer (score 0):

You must have wrongly coded your php script.

Or maybe, there are issues with your web server.

Comment: i can not even load other pages while it's on loop :((